# Oracle SQL Query, Schema Given

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the relations
BOAT(BID, BNAME, COLOUR),
SAILOR(SID, SNAME, AGE, RATING)
RESERVES(BID,SID, DAY)
I want to retrieve the bid of the boats reserved by ALL THE SAILORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct relational divide implementation is here. Others may suggest doing aggregates but that may lead to misleading information in certain cases (false positives)-- "what is there are boats that went unreserved?"

```
SELECT bid FROM Boat WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT sid FROM Sailor WHERE SID NOT IN (SELECT Sid   from Reserves WHERE Sailor.SID = Reserves.SID))
```

Answer (score 0):

If a boat has been reserved by every sailor, the RESERVES.SID count for the boat (counting only unique SIDs) will be the same as the count of sailors:

```
SELECT bid FROM Reserves
GROUP BY bid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sid) = (SELECT COUNT(sid) FROM Sailor)
```